# Using PowerShell AWS CLI To Pass a Tag Value To Variable

Tags: powershell, aws-cli

I can use the following command

`Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{ Name="resource-id"; Values="$( Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content )"}, @{ Name="key"; Value="Env" }`

To display

```
Key ResourceId          ResourceType Value
--- ------------------- ------------ -----
Env i-03a1914ab71c35c63 instance     Dev
```

How would I take the Value (Dev) and make it a variable?

Something like `$Env=Dev` so if I do a `Write-Output $ENV` it shows `Dev`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

`$Env = (Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{ Name="resource-id"; Values="$( Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content )"}, @{ Name="key"; Value="Env" } | select -ExpandProperty value)`